# How to properly render FilteredSelectMultiple

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm using FilteredSelectMultiple widget, but it just doesn't wanna look like the one in the admin.

The Javascript console show

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function        SelectFilter2.js:100
```

My form   (the imported widget: django.contrib.admin.widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple)

```
 class GroupPermissionForm(forms.ModelForm):                                 
     permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(                           
         queryset=Permission.objects.all(),                                  
         widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("verbose name", is_stacked=False)     
     )                                                                       

     class Meta:                                                             
         model = Group                                                       
         fields = ('permissions', )
```

The template

```
{{ group_perm_form.media }}
<form>
  {{ group_perm_form.permissions }}
</form>
```

(I've tried {{ group_perm_form }} too but it didn't work, much to my surprise tho when I rendered the form with crispy I could filter the select input, however it was still broken up)

The order of my javascript files are the following:

```
jquery
django.js
form.media
```

This is the result btw
[image: http://i.imgur.com/pvdcjW1.png]

**edit**: the working template looks like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
{{ group_perm_form.media }}
<form>
  {{ group_perm_form.permissions }}
</form>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/widgets.css" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin JS widgets all have a dependency on the JSI18N script. Add this to in your template header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
```

**Edit**: Looks like you also need the jquery.init.js from static/admin/js, as jQuery is being namespaced to avoid conflicts and isn't passed to the SelectFilter2 script automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!